# Remove all characters after last occurrence of a specific character

Tags: php, character

`Banner-agro-e1498817018351.jpg` is the string I am returning, however, I need to remove `-e1498817018351` and after cleaning I need it as `Banner-agro.jpg`.

the characters after last - can be of undefined length.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Is it always a `jpg` and always a `-`? and/or are the characters after the last `-` always alphanumerical?

Comment: @AlexTartan @chris85 @mshomali I have tried to break down the problem by substring at `.` and then 0th element of array substring at `-`. Ignored the last index and patching it back together. But That's a really complex way, I'm looking for something simpler.

Comment: Maybe https://regex101.com/r/VN5xco/1/?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with following code:

```
<?php
$temp = "Banner-agro-e1498817018351.jpg";
$str = substr($temp, 0, strrpos($temp, '-'));
$ext = substr(strrchr($temp, '.'), 1);
$output = $str .'.'. $ext;
echo $output;
?>
```

You can try this code [here](https://eval.in/826051)

Comment: Please Read the comment above.

Comment: I think my solution is not a complex solution